"Error MSB4018: The "Message" task failed unexpectedly" for ASP.NET Core 8.0 build
I am building an ASP.NET Core 8.0 application for arm64 via a github action. Upon the dotnet restore command, the error in the title is thrown and the build process is aborted. I am building the asp.net template project, there is no additional nuget packages or even additional code. When building the application locally to x64, it works fine.
Here are some relevant files:
Github Workflow file:
name: Build and Push Docker Image

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - testing

jobs:
  build-and-push:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v2
        with:
          platforms: linux/amd64,linux/arm64

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2

      - name: Log in to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Extract version from tag
        id: vars
        run: |
          if [[ "${GITHUB_REF}" == refs/tags/* ]]; then
            echo "VERSION=${GITHUB_REF#refs/tags/}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          else
            echo "VERSION=latest" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          fi

      - name: Build and push Docker image
        run: |
          docker buildx build --no-cache --platform linux/arm64 \
            --tag turwaith/pinfo-backend:latest \
            --push \
            --cache-from=type=registry,ref=turwaith/pinfo-backend:cache \
            --cache-to=type=inline \
            -f PinfoBackend/Dockerfile PinfoBackend/.

Dockerfile
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER $APP_UID
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src

# Copy the project file and restore dependencies
COPY PinfoBackend.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore "PinfoBackend.csproj" --disable-parallel

# Copy all the source code and build the project
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet build "PinfoBackend.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "PinfoBackend.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false /m:1

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "PinfoBackend.dll"]

And the error that is shown in the github action log:
#14 [build 4/6] RUN dotnet restore "PinfoBackend.csproj" --disable-parallel
#14 10.59   Determining projects to restore...
#14 11.54 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.401/NuGet.targets(560,5): error MSB4018: The "Message" task failed unexpectedly. [/src/PinfoBackend.csproj]
#14 11.54 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.401/NuGet.targets(560,5): error MSB4018: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. [/src/PinfoBackend.csproj]
#14 11.54 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.401/NuGet.targets(560,5): error MSB4018:    at InvokeStub_Message.set_Text(Object, Span`1) [/src/PinfoBackend.csproj]
#14 11.54 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.401/NuGet.targets(560,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokePropertySetter(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture) [/src/PinfoBackend.csproj]
#14 11.54 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.401/NuGet.targets(560,14): error MSB4026: The "Text=Restore entry point $(MSBuildProjectFullPath)" parameter for the "Message" task is invalid. [/src/PinfoBackend.csproj]
#14 11.54 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.401/NuGet.targets(560,5): error MSB4063: The "Message" task could not be initialized with its input parameters.  [/src/PinfoBackend.csproj]
#14 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c dotnet restore \"PinfoBackend.csproj\" --disable-parallel" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
------
 > importing cache manifest from ***/pinfo-backend:cache:
------
------
 > [build 4/6] RUN dotnet restore "PinfoBackend.csproj" --disable-parallel:
10.59   Determining projects to restore...
or MSB4018:    at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokePropertySetter(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture) [/src/PinfoBackend.csproj]
11.54 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.401/NuGet.targets(560,14): error MSB4026: The "Text=Restore entry point $(MSBuildProjectFullPath)" parameter for the "Message" task is invalid. [/src/PinfoBackend.csproj]
11.54 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.401/NuGet.targets(560,5): error MSB4063: The "Message" task could not be initialized with its input parameters.  [/src/PinfoBackend.csproj]
------
Dockerfile:12
--------------------
  10 |     # Copy the project file and restore dependencies
  11 |     COPY PinfoBackend.csproj ./
  12 | >>> RUN dotnet restore "PinfoBackend.csproj" --disable-parallel
  13 |     
  14 |     # Copy all the source code and build the project
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c dotnet restore \"PinfoBackend.csproj\" --disable-parallel" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

I have no idea what the message task is and I don't really find anything about that.

Hi @Turwaith, I create a brand new azure web app and enable SCM/FTP Basic Auth Publishing Credentials, then without any other configurations. The last steps is adding github action in deployment center, then it works properly. For more details, please check below answer.

If the issue still occurs, please try to upgrade to higher price tier.

After checking the issue, we can fix the issue by removing below settings in appsettings.json.
                    ,
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://0.0.0.0:5000"
      }
    }
  }

Here is the correct sample code.
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}

I searched github repo by the project name and found yours, here is my github actions history.

And test in my side, it works properly.

